# Is numpy optimized for raspberry-pi automatically

Tags: numpy, optimization, raspberry-pi, arm, neon

The Raspberry Pi ( armv7l architecture ) has neon vfpv4 support which can be used for optimization.

Does the standard version of numpy include these optimizations when installing the command `pip3 install numpy` or `apt-get python3-numpy`?

I am not talking about blas and lapack. Native numpy.

Answer (score 6):

As Mark Setchell noted, `numpy` does not appear to have specific code that targets NEON intrinsics. However, that is not the full story. Modern compilers are frequently able to take serially written code and transform it to use SIMD intrinsics. For instance, GCC can partially unroll loops and use NEON's SIMD instructions to perform multiple iterations of the loop at the same time.

The next thing to note is that `pip install` and `apt-get install` will do different things. `apt-get` will fetch a prebuilt binary from the Raspbian/Debian repository (depending which you are using). Whereas `pip` can only fetch the source of `numpy` when on ARM architectures. This is because the Python Package Index (PyPI) does not store binaries for ARM architectures.

Debian and Raspbian both appear to have `armhf` versions of `python3-numpy` in their repositories. The `hf` stands for "hard float" -- floating point computations done in hardware as opposed to software. This [debian page](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort#NEON) also appears to suggest that `armhf` packages have been compiled to take advantage of NEON intrinsics, but results have been limited. That is, GCC is using the NEON intrinsics, but isn't as finely tuned (yet) as it is when using SSE/SSE2 intrinsics.

`pip` would be the worse option in this case as it appears that GCC is a bit cautious when it comes to targeting ARM floating point instructions. That is, pip will download the numpy source and compile it on your Raspberry Pi, but might not optimise the code as much as it can by default. You will probably need to tell pip to use a few compiler options by using the `--global-option` argument. eg `--global-option="-mfloat-abi=hard"`. You can find a comprehensive set of options to pass [here](https://gist.github.com/fm4dd/c663217935dc17f0fc73c9c81b0aa845).

Comment: Thank you for adding this - the "implicit" optimisations carried out by **GCC** are exactly the area I had reservations about.

Comment: Great answer. If i get a chance I will try to test run times between the two version and update here.

Comment: This is great info. Can you provide an example of the complete command? Specifically, ```pip install numpy --global-option="-mfloat-abit=hard"```, doesn't work for me. I get something along the lines of "error: option -m not recognized." In this case, I'm compiling on an Nvidia TX2, arm cortex a57.

Comment: Great answer, but in the RPi context, isn't this overlooking that on Raspbian pip will work with PiWheels.org thus downloading a wheel rather than source? I'm unsure how the passing of those global options would then work given a precompiled wheel (unless that makes it revert to using the source?)

Answer (score 3):

Chiming in on my recent experience trying to compile numpy and scipy on an Nvidia TX2 to use ARM optimizations. This is a bit different than the original poster's question, in that I'm using a newer ARM architecture, and the compiler flags appropriate for armhf that Dunes references are not all relevant. The TX2 has 4 ARM cortex a57's plus two "Denver" cores (custom ARM cores designed by Nvidia).

This page has the AArch64 compiler options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html

I found the best way to build numpy and scipy with specific compiler optimizations was to create a `site.cfg` file in the project root directory. There is a `site.cfg.example` in the repo (both in scipy and numpy). In the [All] section, I set `extra_compile_args =` line to include those ARM compiler directives of choice. From my experience, I was unable to use the `--global-option` argument of Pip, per Dunes' suggestion, to pass through these flags when building Numpy.

That said, I tried a few different variations of these compiler flags, such as `-mtune=cortex-a57` and was unable to beat the performance as compared to the `python3-numpy` and `python3-scipy` packages available via apt-get. So your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer - January 2019**

I used `readelf` to look at what I believe is the main Numpy shared object library on my Raspberry Pi as follows:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core
readelf -a -W multiarray.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so

ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xe068
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          1283864 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000400, Version5 EABI, hard-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         28
  Section header string table index: 27
  ...
  ...
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "6"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v6
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

I noted that **none** of the following are present, so I still think Numpy doesn't use NEON SIMD on Raspberry Pi. I am very happy to be told I am wrong if anyone knows better!!!! Please do.

```
Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
```

**Updated Answer - November 2018**

You can check the way Numpy was compiled as below:

```
import pprint
import numpy.distutils

config_vars = numpy.distutils.unixccompiler.sysconfig.get_config_vars()

pprint.pprint(config_vars)
```

And I get this - still no mention of NEON:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy.distutils
>>> np_config_vars = numpy.distutils.unixccompiler.sysconfig.get_config_vars()
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(np_config_vars)
{'AC_APPLE_UNIVERSAL_BUILD': 0,
 'AIX_GENUINE_CPLUSPLUS': 0,
 'AR': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar',
 'ARFLAGS': 'rc',
 'ASDLGEN': '../Parser/asdl_c.py',
 'ASDLGEN_FILES': '../Parser/asdl.py ../Parser/asdl_c.py',
 'AST_ASDL': '../Parser/Python.asdl',
 'AST_C': 'Python/Python-ast.c',
 'AST_C_DIR': 'Python',
 'AST_H': 'Include/Python-ast.h',
 'AST_H_DIR': 'Include',
 'ATHEOS_THREADS': 0,
 'BASECFLAGS': '-fno-strict-aliasing',
 'BASEMODLIBS': '',
 'BEOS_THREADS': 0,
 'BINDIR': '/usr/bin',
 'BINLIBDEST': '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 'BLDLIBRARY': '-L. -lpython2.7',
 'BLDSHARED': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  ',
 'BUILDEXE': '',
 'BUILDPYTHON': 'python',
 'CC': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread',
 'CCSHARED': '-fPIC',
 'CFLAGS': '-fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  ',
 'CFLAGSFORSHARED': '-fPIC',
 'CONFIGFILES': 'configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.in',
 'CONFIGURE_CFLAGS': '-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security',
 'CONFIGURE_CPPFLAGS': '',
 'CONFIGURE_LDFLAGS': '-Wl,-z,relro',
 'CONFIG_ARGS': "'--enable-shared' '--prefix=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-unicode=ucs4' '--with-dbmliborder=bdb:gdbm' '--with-system-expat' '--with-computed-gotos' '--with-system-ffi' '--with-fpectl' 'CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' 'CFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro'",
 'CONFINCLUDEDIR': '/usr/include',
 'CONFINCLUDEPY': '/usr/include/python2.7',
 'COREPYTHONPATH': ':plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf:lib-tk:lib-old',
 'COVERAGE_INFO': '/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13/build-shared/coverage.info',
 'COVERAGE_REPORT': '/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13/build-shared/lcov-report',
 'COVERAGE_REPORT_OPTIONS': '--no-branch-coverage --title "CPython lcov report"',
 'CPPFLAGS': '-I. -IInclude -I../Include',
 'CXX': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -pthread',
 'C_THREADS': 0,
 'DEBUG_EXT': '',
 'DESTDIRS': '/usr /usr/lib /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 'DESTLIB': '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 'DESTPATH': '',
 'DESTSHARED': '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 'DIRMODE': 755,
 'DIST': 'README ChangeLog configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.in Include Lib Misc Demo Ext-dummy',
 'DISTDIRS': 'Include Lib Misc Demo Ext-dummy',
 'DISTFILES': 'README ChangeLog configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.in',
 'DLINCLDIR': '.',
 'DLLLIBRARY': '',
 'DOUBLE_IS_ARM_MIXED_ENDIAN_IEEE754': 0,
 'DOUBLE_IS_BIG_ENDIAN_IEEE754': 0,
 'DOUBLE_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN_IEEE754': 1,
 'DYNLOADFILE': 'dynload_shlib.o',
 'ENABLE_IPV6': 1,
 'ENSUREPIP': 'no',
 'EXE': '',
 'EXEMODE': 755,
 'EXTRAMACHDEPPATH': '',
 'EXTRAPLATDIR': '',
 'EXTRATESTOPTS': '',
 'FILEMODE': 644,
 'FLOCK_NEEDS_LIBBSD': 0,
 'GETPGRP_HAVE_ARG': 0,
 'GETTIMEOFDAY_NO_TZ': 0,
 'GLHACK': '-Dclear=__GLclear',
 'GNULD': 'yes',
 'GRAMMAR_C': 'Python/graminit.c',
 'GRAMMAR_H': 'Include/graminit.h',
 'GRAMMAR_INPUT': '../Grammar/Grammar',
 'HAVE_ACOSH': 1,
 'HAVE_ADDRINFO': 1,
 'HAVE_ALARM': 1,
 'HAVE_ALLOCA_H': 1,
 'HAVE_ALTZONE': 0,
 'HAVE_ASINH': 1,
 'HAVE_ASM_TYPES_H': 1,
 'HAVE_ATANH': 1,
 'HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT_PARSETUPLE': 0,
 'HAVE_BIND_TEXTDOMAIN_CODESET': 1,
 'HAVE_BLUETOOTH_BLUETOOTH_H': 1,
 'HAVE_BLUETOOTH_H': 0,
 'HAVE_BROKEN_NICE': 0,
 'HAVE_BROKEN_PIPE_BUF': 0,
 'HAVE_BROKEN_POLL': 0,
 'HAVE_BROKEN_POSIX_SEMAPHORES': 0,
 'HAVE_BROKEN_PTHREAD_SIGMASK': 0,
 'HAVE_BROKEN_SEM_GETVALUE': 0,
 'HAVE_BROKEN_UNSETENV': 0,
 'HAVE_C99_BOOL': 1,
 'HAVE_CHFLAGS': 0,
 'HAVE_CHOWN': 1,
 'HAVE_CHROOT': 1,
 'HAVE_CLOCK': 1,
 'HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTOS': 1,
 'HAVE_CONFSTR': 1,
 'HAVE_CONIO_H': 0,
 'HAVE_COPYSIGN': 1,
 'HAVE_CTERMID': 1,
 'HAVE_CTERMID_R': 0,
 'HAVE_CURSES_H': 1,
 'HAVE_CURSES_IS_TERM_RESIZED': 1,
 'HAVE_CURSES_RESIZETERM': 1,
 'HAVE_CURSES_RESIZE_TERM': 1,
 'HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE': 1,
 'HAVE_DECL_ISINF': 1,
 'HAVE_DECL_ISNAN': 1,
 'HAVE_DECL_TZNAME': 0,
 'HAVE_DEVICE_MACROS': 1,
 'HAVE_DEV_PTC': 0,
 'HAVE_DEV_PTMX': 1,
 'HAVE_DIRECT_H': 0,
 'HAVE_DIRENT_H': 1,
 'HAVE_DLFCN_H': 1,
 'HAVE_DLOPEN': 1,
 'HAVE_DUP2': 1,
 'HAVE_DYNAMIC_LOADING': 1,
 'HAVE_EPOLL': 1,
 'HAVE_ERF': 1,
 'HAVE_ERFC': 1,
 'HAVE_ERRNO_H': 1,
 'HAVE_EXECV': 1,
 'HAVE_EXPM1': 1,
 'HAVE_FCHDIR': 1,
 'HAVE_FCHMOD': 1,
 'HAVE_FCHOWN': 1,
 'HAVE_FCNTL_H': 1,
 'HAVE_FDATASYNC': 1,
 'HAVE_FINITE': 1,
 'HAVE_FLOCK': 1,
 'HAVE_FORK': 1,
 'HAVE_FORKPTY': 1,
 'HAVE_FPATHCONF': 1,
 'HAVE_FSEEK64': 0,
 'HAVE_FSEEKO': 1,
 'HAVE_FSTATVFS': 1,
 'HAVE_FSYNC': 1,
 'HAVE_FTELL64': 0,
 'HAVE_FTELLO': 1,
 'HAVE_FTIME': 1,
 'HAVE_FTRUNCATE': 1,
 'HAVE_GAI_STRERROR': 1,
 'HAVE_GAMMA': 1,
 'HAVE_GCC_ASM_FOR_X87': 0,
 'HAVE_GETADDRINFO': 1,
 'HAVE_GETCWD': 1,
 'HAVE_GETC_UNLOCKED': 1,
 'HAVE_GETENTROPY': 0,
 'HAVE_GETGROUPS': 1,
 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME': 0,
 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R': 1,
 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG': 0,
 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG': 0,
 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG': 1,
 'HAVE_GETITIMER': 1,
 'HAVE_GETLOADAVG': 1,
 'HAVE_GETLOGIN': 1,
 'HAVE_GETNAMEINFO': 1,
 'HAVE_GETPAGESIZE': 1,
 'HAVE_GETPEERNAME': 1,
 'HAVE_GETPGID': 1,
 'HAVE_GETPGRP': 1,
 'HAVE_GETPID': 1,
 'HAVE_GETPRIORITY': 1,
 'HAVE_GETPWENT': 1,
 'HAVE_GETRESGID': 1,
 'HAVE_GETRESUID': 1,
 'HAVE_GETSID': 1,
 'HAVE_GETSPENT': 1,
 'HAVE_GETSPNAM': 1,
 'HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY': 1,
 'HAVE_GETWD': 1,
 'HAVE_GRP_H': 1,
 'HAVE_HSTRERROR': 1,
 'HAVE_HYPOT': 1,
 'HAVE_IEEEFP_H': 0,
 'HAVE_INET_ATON': 1,
 'HAVE_INET_PTON': 1,
 'HAVE_INITGROUPS': 1,
 'HAVE_INT32_T': 1,
 'HAVE_INT64_T': 1,
 'HAVE_INTTYPES_H': 1,
 'HAVE_IO_H': 0,
 'HAVE_KILL': 1,
 'HAVE_KILLPG': 1,
 'HAVE_KQUEUE': 0,
 'HAVE_LANGINFO_H': 1,
 'HAVE_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT': 1,
 'HAVE_LCHFLAGS': 0,
 'HAVE_LCHMOD': 0,
 'HAVE_LCHOWN': 1,
 'HAVE_LGAMMA': 1,
 'HAVE_LIBDL': 1,
 'HAVE_LIBDLD': 0,
 'HAVE_LIBIEEE': 0,
 'HAVE_LIBINTL_H': 1,
 'HAVE_LIBREADLINE': 1,
 'HAVE_LIBRESOLV': 0,
 'HAVE_LIBUTIL_H': 0,
 'HAVE_LINK': 1,
 'HAVE_LINUX_NETLINK_H': 1,
 'HAVE_LINUX_TIPC_H': 1,
 'HAVE_LOG1P': 1,
 'HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE': 1,
 'HAVE_LONG_LONG': 1,
 'HAVE_LSTAT': 1,
 'HAVE_MAKEDEV': 1,
 'HAVE_MEMMOVE': 1,
 'HAVE_MEMORY_H': 1,
 'HAVE_MKFIFO': 1,
 'HAVE_MKNOD': 1,
 'HAVE_MKTIME': 1,
 'HAVE_MMAP': 1,
 'HAVE_MREMAP': 1,
 'HAVE_NCURSES_H': 1,
 'HAVE_NDIR_H': 0,
 'HAVE_NETPACKET_PACKET_H': 1,
 'HAVE_NICE': 1,
 'HAVE_OPENPTY': 1,
 'HAVE_OSX105_SDK': 0,
 'HAVE_PATHCONF': 1,
 'HAVE_PAUSE': 1,
 'HAVE_PLOCK': 0,
 'HAVE_POLL': 1,
 'HAVE_POLL_H': 1,
 'HAVE_PROCESS_H': 0,
 'HAVE_PROTOTYPES': 1,
 'HAVE_PTH': 0,
 'HAVE_PTHREAD_ATFORK': 1,
 'HAVE_PTHREAD_DESTRUCTOR': 0,
 'HAVE_PTHREAD_H': 1,
 'HAVE_PTHREAD_INIT': 0,
 'HAVE_PTHREAD_SIGMASK': 1,
 'HAVE_PTY_H': 1,
 'HAVE_PUTENV': 1,
 'HAVE_READLINK': 1,
 'HAVE_REALPATH': 1,
 'HAVE_RL_CALLBACK': 1,
 'HAVE_RL_CATCH_SIGNAL': 1,
 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER': 1,
 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_DISPLAY_MATCHES_HOOK': 1,
 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES': 1,
 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_SUPPRESS_APPEND': 1,
 'HAVE_RL_PRE_INPUT_HOOK': 1,
 'HAVE_RL_RESIZE_TERMINAL': 1,
 'HAVE_ROUND': 1,
 'HAVE_SELECT': 1,
 'HAVE_SEM_GETVALUE': 1,
 'HAVE_SEM_OPEN': 1,
 'HAVE_SEM_TIMEDWAIT': 1,
 'HAVE_SEM_UNLINK': 1,
 'HAVE_SETEGID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETEUID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETGID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETGROUPS': 1,
 'HAVE_SETITIMER': 1,
 'HAVE_SETLOCALE': 1,
 'HAVE_SETPGID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETPGRP': 1,
 'HAVE_SETREGID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETRESGID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETRESUID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETREUID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETSID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETUID': 1,
 'HAVE_SETVBUF': 1,
 'HAVE_SHADOW_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SIGACTION': 1,
 'HAVE_SIGINTERRUPT': 1,
 'HAVE_SIGNAL_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SIGRELSE': 1,
 'HAVE_SNPRINTF': 1,
 'HAVE_SOCKADDR_SA_LEN': 0,
 'HAVE_SOCKADDR_STORAGE': 1,
 'HAVE_SOCKETPAIR': 1,
 'HAVE_SPAWN_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SSIZE_T': 1,
 'HAVE_STATVFS': 1,
 'HAVE_STAT_TV_NSEC': 1,
 'HAVE_STAT_TV_NSEC2': 0,
 'HAVE_STDARG_PROTOTYPES': 1,
 'HAVE_STDINT_H': 1,
 'HAVE_STDLIB_H': 1,
 'HAVE_STRDUP': 1,
 'HAVE_STRFTIME': 1,
 'HAVE_STRINGS_H': 1,
 'HAVE_STRING_H': 1,
 'HAVE_STROPTS_H': 1,
 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIME': 0,
 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BLKSIZE': 1,
 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BLOCKS': 1,
 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_FLAGS': 0,
 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_GEN': 0,
 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_RDEV': 1,
 'HAVE_STRUCT_TM_TM_ZONE': 1,
 'HAVE_SYMLINK': 1,
 'HAVE_SYSCONF': 1,
 'HAVE_SYSEXITS_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_AUDIOIO_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_BSDTTY_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_DIR_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_EPOLL_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_EVENT_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_FILE_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_LOADAVG_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_LOCK_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_MKDEV_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_MODEM_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_NDIR_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_PARAM_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_POLL_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_RESOURCE_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_STATVFS_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_STAT_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_TERMIO_H': 0,
 'HAVE_SYS_TIMES_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_TIME_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_UN_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_UTSNAME_H': 1,
 'HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H': 1,
 'HAVE_TCGETPGRP': 1,
 'HAVE_TCSETPGRP': 1,
 'HAVE_TEMPNAM': 1,
 'HAVE_TERMIOS_H': 1,
 'HAVE_TERM_H': 1,
 'HAVE_TGAMMA': 1,
 'HAVE_THREAD_H': 0,
 'HAVE_TIMEGM': 1,
 'HAVE_TIMES': 1,
 'HAVE_TMPFILE': 1,
 'HAVE_TMPNAM': 1,
 'HAVE_TMPNAM_R': 1,
 'HAVE_TM_ZONE': 1,
 'HAVE_TRUNCATE': 1,
 'HAVE_TZNAME': 0,
 'HAVE_UCS4_TCL': 0,
 'HAVE_UINT32_T': 1,
 'HAVE_UINT64_T': 1,
 'HAVE_UINTPTR_T': 1,
 'HAVE_UNAME': 1,
 'HAVE_UNISTD_H': 1,
 'HAVE_UNSETENV': 1,
 'HAVE_USABLE_WCHAR_T': 1,
 'HAVE_UTIL_H': 0,
 'HAVE_UTIMES': 1,
 'HAVE_UTIME_H': 1,
 'HAVE_WAIT3': 1,
 'HAVE_WAIT4': 1,
 'HAVE_WAITPID': 1,
 'HAVE_WCHAR_H': 1,
 'HAVE_WCSCOLL': 1,
 'HAVE_WORKING_TZSET': 1,
 'HAVE_ZLIB_COPY': 1,
 'HAVE__GETPTY': 0,
 'HGBRANCH': '',
 'HGTAG': '',
 'HGVERSION': '',
 'HOST_GNU_TYPE': 'armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf',
 'HURD_C_THREADS': 0,
 'INCLDIRSTOMAKE': '/usr/include /usr/include /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7',
 'INCLUDEDIR': '/usr/include',
 'INCLUDEPY': '/usr/include/python2.7',
 'INSTALL': '/usr/bin/install -c',
 'INSTALL_DATA': '/usr/bin/install -c -m 644',
 'INSTALL_PROGRAM': '/usr/bin/install -c',
 'INSTALL_SCRIPT': '/usr/bin/install -c',
 'INSTALL_SHARED': '/usr/bin/install -c -m 555',
 'INSTSONAME': 'libpython2.7.so.1.0',
 'LDCXXSHARED': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions',
 'LDFLAGS': '-Wl,-z,relro',
 'LDLAST': '',
 'LDLIBRARY': 'libpython2.7.so',
 'LDLIBRARYDIR': '',
 'LDSHARED': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  ',
 'LIBC': '',
 'LIBDEST': '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 'LIBDIR': '/usr/lib',
 'LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR': '',
 'LIBM': '-lm',
 'LIBOBJDIR': 'Python/',
 'LIBOBJS': '',
 'LIBP': '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 'LIBPC': '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig',
 'LIBPL': '/usr/lib/python2.7/config-arm-linux-gnueabihf',
 'LIBRARY': 'libpython2.7.a',
 'LIBRARY_OBJS': '\\',
 'LIBS': '-lpthread -ldl  -lutil',
 'LIBSUBDIRS': 'lib-tk lib-tk/test lib-tk/test/test_tkinter \\',
 'LINKCC': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread',
 'LINKFORSHARED': '-Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions',
 'LLVM_PROF_ERR': 'no',
 'LLVM_PROF_FILE': '',
 'LLVM_PROF_MERGER': 'true',
 'LN': 'ln',
 'LOCALMODLIBS': '-L/usr/lib -lz',
 'MACHDEP': 'linux2',
 'MACHDEPPATH': ':plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf',
 'MACHDEPS': 'plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf',
 'MACHDEP_OBJS': '',
 'MACHDESTLIB': '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 'MACH_C_THREADS': 0,
 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET': '',
 'MAINCC': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread',
 'MAJOR_IN_MKDEV': 0,
 'MAJOR_IN_SYSMACROS': 0,
 'MAKESETUP': '../Modules/makesetup',
 'MANDIR': '/usr/share/man',
 'MEMTESTOPTS': '-l -x test_subprocess test_io test_lib2to3 \\ -x test_dl test___all__ test_fork1 \\',
 'MKDIR_P': '/bin/mkdir -p',
 'MODLIBS': '-L/usr/lib -lz',
 'MODOBJS': 'Modules/threadmodule.o  Modules/signalmodule.o  Modules/arraymodule.o  Modules/cmathmodule.o  Modules/mathmodule.o Modules/_math.o  Modules/_struct.o  Modules/timemodule.o  Modules/operator.o  Modules/_randommodule.o  Modules/_collectionsmodule.o  Modules/_heapqmodule.o  Modules/itertoolsmodule.o  Modules/stropmodule.o  Modules/_functoolsmodule.o  Modules/datetimemodule.o  Modules/_bisectmodule.o  Modules/unicodedata.o  Modules/_localemodule.o  Modules/bufferedio.o Modules/bytesio.o Modules/fileio.o Modules/iobase.o Modules/_iomodule.o Modules/stringio.o Modules/textio.o  Modules/fcntlmodule.o  Modules/spwdmodule.o  Modules/grpmodule.o  Modules/selectmodule.o  Modules/socketmodule.o Modules/timemodule.o  Modules/md5module.o Modules/md5.o  Modules/shamodule.o  Modules/sha256module.o  Modules/sha512module.o  Modules/syslogmodule.o  Modules/binascii.o  Modules/cStringIO.o  Modules/cPickle.o  Modules/zlibmodule.o  Modules/posixmodule.o  Modules/errnomodule.o  Modules/pwdmodule.o  Modules/_sre.o  Modules/_codecsmodule.o  Modules/_weakref.o  Modules/zipimport.o  Modules/symtablemodule.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o',
 'MODULE_OBJS': '\\',
 'MULTIARCH': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf',
 'MVWDELCH_IS_EXPRESSION': 1,
 'OBJECT_OBJS': '\\',
 'OLDPATH': ':lib-old',
 'OPCODETARGETGEN': '\\',
 'OPCODETARGETGEN_FILES': '\\',
 'OPCODETARGETS_H': '\\',
 'OPT': '-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes',
 'OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT': '',
 'PACKAGE_BUGREPORT': 0,
 'PACKAGE_NAME': 0,
 'PACKAGE_STRING': 0,
 'PACKAGE_TARNAME': 0,
 'PACKAGE_URL': 0,
 'PACKAGE_VERSION': 0,
 'PARSER_HEADERS': '\\',
 'PARSER_OBJS': '\\ Parser/myreadline.o Parser/tokenizer.o',
 'PGEN': 'Parser/pgen',
 'PGENOBJS': '\\ \\',
 'PGENSRCS': '\\ \\',
 'PGOBJS': '\\',
 'PGO_PROF_GEN_FLAG': '-fprofile-generate',
 'PGO_PROF_USE_FLAG': '',
 'PGSRCS': '\\',
 'PLATDIR': 'plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf',
 'PLATMACDIRS': 'plat-mac plat-mac/Carbon plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages \\',
 'PLATMACPATH': ':plat-mac:plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 'POBJS': '\\',
 'POSIX_SEMAPHORES_NOT_ENABLED': 0,
 'PROFILE_TASK': '-m test.regrtest --pgo -x test_asyncore test_gdb test_multiprocessing test_subprocess',
 'PSRCS': '\\',
 'PTHREAD_SYSTEM_SCHED_SUPPORTED': 1,
 'PURIFY': '',
 'PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT': 0,
 'PYTHON': 'python',
 'PYTHONFRAMEWORK': '',
 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR': 'no-framework',
 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR': '',
 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX': '',
 'PYTHONPATH': ':plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf:lib-tk:lib-old',
 'PYTHON_FOR_BUILD': './python -E',
 'PYTHON_HEADERS': '\\',
 'PYTHON_OBJS': '\\',
 'PY_CFLAGS': '-fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  ',
 'PY_CORE_CFLAGS': '-fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -I. -IInclude -I../Include -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE',
 'PY_CPPFLAGS': '-I. -IInclude -I../Include',
 'PY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG': '"ll"',
 'PY_FORMAT_SIZE_T': '"z"',
 'PY_LDFLAGS': '-Wl,-z,relro',
 'PY_UNICODE_TYPE': 'wchar_t',
 'Py_DEBUG': 0,
 'Py_ENABLE_SHARED': 1,
 'Py_UNICODE_SIZE': 4,
 'Py_USING_UNICODE': 1,
 'QUICKTESTOPTS': '-l -x test_subprocess test_io test_lib2to3 \\',
 'RANLIB': 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib',
 'RESSRCDIR': 'Mac/Resources/framework',
 'RETSIGTYPE': 'void',
 'RUNSHARED': 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13/build-shared',
 'SCRIPTDIR': '/usr/lib',
 'SETPGRP_HAVE_ARG': 0,
 'SGI_ABI': '',
 'SHELL': '/bin/sh',
 'SHLIBS': '-lpthread -ldl  -lutil',
 'SHLIB_EXT': '".so"',
 'SIGNAL_OBJS': '',
 'SIGNED_RIGHT_SHIFT_ZERO_FILLS': 0,
 'SITEPATH': '',
 'SIZEOF_DOUBLE': 8,
 'SIZEOF_FLOAT': 4,
 'SIZEOF_FPOS_T': 16,
 'SIZEOF_INT': 4,
 'SIZEOF_LONG': 4,
 'SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE': 8,
 'SIZEOF_LONG_LONG': 8,
 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': 8,
 'SIZEOF_PID_T': 4,
 'SIZEOF_PTHREAD_T': 4,
 'SIZEOF_SHORT': 2,
 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T': 4,
 'SIZEOF_TIME_T': 4,
 'SIZEOF_UINTPTR_T': 4,
 'SIZEOF_VOID_P': 4,
 'SIZEOF_WCHAR_T': 4,
 'SIZEOF__BOOL': 1,
 'SO': '.so',
 'SRCDIRS': 'Parser Grammar Objects Python Modules Mac',
 'SRC_GDB_HOOKS': '../Tools/gdb/libpython.py',
 'STDC_HEADERS': 1,
 'STRICT_SYSV_CURSES': "/* Don't use ncurses extensions */",
 'STRINGLIB_HEADERS': '\\',
 'SUBDIRS': '',
 'SUBDIRSTOO': 'Include Lib Misc Demo',
 'SVNVERSION': 'echo Unversioned directory',
 'SYSLIBS': '-lm',
 'SYS_SELECT_WITH_SYS_TIME': 1,
 'TANH_PRESERVES_ZERO_SIGN': 1,
 'TCLTK_INCLUDES': '',
 'TCLTK_LIBS': '',
 'TESTOPTS': '-l',
 'TESTPATH': '',
 'TESTPROG': '../Lib/test/regrtest.py',
 'TESTPYTHON': 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13/build-shared ./python -Wd -3 -E -tt',
 'TESTPYTHONOPTS': '',
 'THREADOBJ': 'Python/thread.o',
 'TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME': 1,
 'TKPATH': ':lib-tk',
 'TM_IN_SYS_TIME': 0,
 'UNICODE_OBJS': 'Objects/unicodeobject.o Objects/unicodectype.o',
 'UNIVERSALSDK': '',
 'USE_COMPUTED_GOTOS': 1,
 'USE_TOOLBOX_OBJECT_GLUE': 0,
 'VA_LIST_IS_ARRAY': 0,
 'VERSION': '2.7',
 'VPATH': '..',
 'WANT_SIGFPE_HANDLER': 1,
 'WANT_WCTYPE_FUNCTIONS': 0,
 'WINDOW_HAS_FLAGS': 1,
 'WITH_DOC_STRINGS': 1,
 'WITH_DYLD': 0,
 'WITH_LIBINTL': 0,
 'WITH_NEXT_FRAMEWORK': 0,
 'WITH_PYMALLOC': 1,
 'WITH_THREAD': 1,
 'WITH_TSC': 0,
 'WITH_VALGRIND': 0,
 'X87_DOUBLE_ROUNDING': 0,
 'XMLLIBSUBDIRS': 'xml xml/dom xml/etree xml/parsers xml/sax',
 'abs_builddir': '/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13/build-shared',
 'abs_srcdir': '/build/python2.7-9xgeTe/python2.7-2.7.13/build-shared/..',
 'build': 'armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf',
 'datarootdir': '/usr/share',
 'exec_prefix': '/usr',
 'host': 'armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf',
 'prefix': '/usr',
 'srcdir': '..'}
```

---

**Original Answer**

I downloaded the `numpy` source from [Github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) and searched all the files for anything related to NEON, Raspberry Pi, VFPV3/4 and found nothing at all:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Ei "neon|vfpv|rasp" {} +

./branding/icons/numpylogoicon.svg:BdKSolPgKfvIDPs6QVBky6rDZ0tZyoXr6VFPV93bY8uBGX82cde4ykqhH6ULoF2veusIosa1reLm
./doc/neps/nep-0021-advanced-indexing.rst:Since the various kinds of indexing is hard to grasp in many cases, these
./doc/neps/nep-0021-advanced-indexing.rst:These examples may be hard to grasp without working knowledge of advanced
./doc/source/reference/c-api.rst:grasp. This is especially true because of the code-generation
./numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc.src: * In future it may contain other instruction sets like AVX or NEON detected
```

I'm no expert on `numpy` but I'll stick my neck out and say there is no support for NEON in the current `numpy` version.