# Numpy import failed

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi

On an RPi2, I upgraded all my packages with pip-review and numpy does not work anymore.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall numpy though pip and apt but I'm getting no luck.

Apt installs numpy 1.12.1, if I try to install that it does not install through pip.

Pip installs numpy 1.16.4 fine, but when I go to run it I get the error below.

I have already run: sudo apt install libc6 libatlas-base-dev

Any help is appreciated.

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, May  8 2019, 18:07:21) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using /usr/local/bin/python3),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

Comment: What do you get from `ldd --version` and `ls /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ |grep libm.so` ?

Comment: @Christoffer ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) 2.24
and libm.so.6

Comment: It seems that numpy was compiled towards glibc 2.27 and you are running 2.24. You can either recompile numpy to your version or upgrade glibc. BUT upgrading glibc might have an effect on all your other packages at stated here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/645108/upgrading-glibc-to-a-version-at-least-2-17-or-higher-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: I have been struggling with this exact same issue on my RPi3. I have not found a solution yet, I think the operating system is not yet updated to work with python 3.7.3. I am using Python 3.5.5 in the meantime. If you do find a solution, please post it here.

Comment: I installed raspbian buster and the corresponding numpy package, that seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

pip install numpy --global-option="-mfloat-abi=hard" --force-reinstall was the only answer that worked for me . The explanation is given in a thread on a slightly different problem see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161063/is-numpy-optimized-for-raspberry-pi-automatically/52415084#52415084)

Comment: This should be the real answer if the problem is tied to glibc version. Here on `stretch` I have `ldd --version` that gives  `ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) 2.24` and that is below `GLIBC_2.27`. As there seems to be no way to upgrade to 2.27 in stretch (and it risks breaking other stuff) a numpy install with `pip install numpy --global-option="-mfloat-abi=hard" --force-reinstall ` seems to be only way through

Answer (score 0):

With Conda it is solved depending on the version, but must force reinstall.

```py
# versions >= 4.6:
conda install numpy --force-reinstall

# versions < 4.6:
conda install numpy --force
```