# ImportError: undefined symbol zmq_strerror

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, jupyter-notebook, pyzmq

I'm trying to install Jupyter Notebook to run the TensorFlow 2 models tutorial. (https://tensorflow2objectdetectioninstallation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tensorflow-models-installation) The packages seemed to have installed fine but when I try to run:

`jupyter notebook`
or `python3.7 -m jupyter notebook`

I get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/stonesoup_testing/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection $ python3.7 -m jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 51, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/error.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: zmq_strerror
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/stonesoup_testing/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection $
```

On Raspbian Stretch, using Python 3.7, pymzq version: 19.0.2

here is my `pip freeze` output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/stonesoup_testing/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection $ python3.7 -m pip freeze
actionlib==1.11.13
angles==1.9.11
argon2-cffi==20.1.0
attrs==20.1.0
backcall==0.2.0
bleach==3.1.5
bondpy==1.8.3
camera-calibration-parsers==1.11.13
catkin==0.7.14
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.2
cv-bridge==1.12.8
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.21
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
diagnostic-analysis==1.9.3
diagnostic-common-diagnostics==1.9.3
diagnostic-updater==1.9.3
dynamic-reconfigure==1.5.50
entrypoints==0.3
gencpp==0.6.0
geneus==2.2.6
genlisp==0.4.16
genmsg==0.5.11
gennodejs==2.0.1
genpy==0.6.7
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
ipykernel==5.3.4
ipymd==0.1.3
ipython==7.18.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
jedi==0.17.2
Jinja2==2.11.2
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==6.1.7
jupyter-console==6.2.0
jupyter-core==4.6.3
kiwisolver==1.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.1
message-filters==1.12.14
mistune==0.8.4
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.0.7
notebook==6.1.3
numpy==1.19.1
object-detection==0.1
packaging==20.4
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.7.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==7.2.0
pluginlib==1.11.3
prometheus-client==0.8.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.7
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.6.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent==0.16.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-qt-binding==0.3.4
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==19.0.2
qtconsole==4.7.6
QtPy==1.9.0
resource-retriever==1.12.4
rosbag==1.12.14
rosboost-cfg==1.14.4
rosclean==1.14.4
roscreate==1.14.4
rosgraph==1.12.14
roslaunch==1.12.14
roslib==1.14.4
roslint==0.11.0
roslz4==1.12.14
rosmake==1.14.4
rosmaster==1.12.14
rosmsg==1.12.14
rosnode==1.12.14
rosparam==1.12.14
rospy==1.12.14
rosserial-python==0.7.7
rosservice==1.12.14
rostest==1.12.14
rostopic==1.12.14
rosunit==1.14.4
roswtf==1.12.14
Send2Trash==1.5.0
sensor-msgs==1.12.7
six==1.15.0
smach==2.0.1
smach-ros==2.0.1
smclib==1.8.3
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
tf==1.11.9
tf-conversions==1.11.9
tf2-kdl==0.5.20
tf2-py==0.5.20
tf2-ros==0.5.20
topic-tools==1.12.14
tornado==6.0.4
traitlets==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
xacro==1.11.3
zipp==3.1.0
zmq==0.0.0
```

Comment: Hi, kindly share the pyzmq version?

Comment: do a pip freeze and paste the output here.

Comment: @yodebu added to the end of the post (too many chars)

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled pyzmq and built it from source instead. This solved my issue and I can run jupyter notebook fine now. I'm now having a different problem where numpy is not importing properly from within jupyter.

Comment: pip install numpy --global-option="-mfloat-abi=hard" --force-reinstall from here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56785686/numpy-import-failed/62084261 worked for me.